# ValueError: Layer #4 (named "predictions") expects 2 weight(s), but the saved weights have 0 element(s)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After used Keras retrain the InceptionV3 model, after retrain I use cpu machine to do the testing and then get below info. I think it was case by I used the multiple gpu to do the retraining and use one cpu machine to do testing. I also try to add `inception3_model = multi_gpu_model(inception3_model, gpus=2)` , but it did not work because testing env is cpu env.

error message:

```
2018-07-19 18:07:21.957595: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/ICD/Documents/source/mofang_UserActivity/UserActivityAnlyse/branches/tensorflow/server/vehicle_django/util/test.py", line 105, in <module>
        verify_h5model(args)
      File "/Users/ICD/Documents/source/mofang_UserActivity/UserActivityAnlyse/branches/tensorflow/server/vehicle_django/util/test.py", line 42, in verify_h5model
        inceptionV3_model.load_weights(weights_path, by_name=True)
      File "/Users/ICD/Documents/workspace/vm/tensorflow_imageRetrain/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1177, in load_weights
        reshape=reshape)
      File "/Users/ICD/Documents/workspace/vm/tensorflow_imageRetrain/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 1000, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name
        ' element(s).')
    ValueError: Layer #4 (named "predictions") expects 2 weight(s), but the saved weights have 0 element(s).
```

prediction code

```
#with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
#     inception = InceptionV3(include_top=False, weights=None,
#                             input_tensor=None, pooling='avg', input_shape=(299, 299, 3))
#     output = inception.get_layer(index=-1).output  # shape=(None, 1, 1, 2048)
#     output = Dense(1024, name='features')(output)
#     # output = Dense(41, activation='softmax', name='predictions_request')(output)
#     output = Dense(41, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(output)
#     inception3_model = Model(outputs=output, inputs=inception.input)
# 
# inception3_model = multi_gpu_model(inception3_model, gpus=2)
# inception3_model.load_weights(weights_path, by_name=True)

InceptionV3_model = load_model(weights_path)

img = Image.open(BytesIO(byte_date))
width_height_tuple = (299, 299)
img = img.convert('RGB')
img = img.resize(width_height_tuple, Image.NEAREST)
i = image.img_to_array(img)
i = np.expand_dims(i, axis=0)
i = preprocess_input(i)
prediInceptionV3_model.predict(i)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error when going from multi-gpu training to single-gpu testing.

Comment: yep, bcz multi_gpu_model will separate the index and weight when call the function, the solution pls refer to my other article
https://blog.csdn.net/lzcong1986/article/details/81154803